# How can I get this to run without freezing the GUI

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

This is a very simplified version of my code to get a better understanding of what I'm doing wrong here. The GUI freezes if the button is pressed. I need to be able to run a while loop if the button is pressed without freezing.

```
class obj1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("this thread should run when the button is pressed and I should be able to press another button");
        }
    }
}

class GUI extends Thread{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("test1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("test2");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String command;

    public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();

        buttonOnAction();
    }


    public void buttonOnAction(){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                obj1 one = new obj1();
                one.start();
                one.run();
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                obj1 one2 = new obj1();
                one2.start();
                one2.run();

            }
        });
    }
}


public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
            GUI gui = new GUI();
            gui.start();
            gui.run();
   }
}
```

Why does the GUI freeze?

Comment: Never call `run` directly, that is what `start` is for. Beyond that, make sure you aren't performing logic on the event dispatch thread (especially an infinite loop).

Comment: Don't call `run` - it's not how threads work

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: And never use a `while(true)` busy-wait; that can be enough to cripple your system all on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `run()` directly on your `Thread` object. This immediately executes the `run()` method and doesn't spawn a new thread. Instead, just call `start()` as you have and let the system create the thread and call `run()` when it decides to.

Comment: Dude you're a life saver

Comment: Since I am no longer calling run(), do you know how I could feed the run method a string?

tool4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                command ="powershell.exe wf";
                Console con4 = new Console();
                con4.start();
                try {
                    con4.run(command);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

Comment: @newToCpp you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth pointing out that the proper way to schedule *graphical* work in Swing is to make sure it ends up on the event dispatch thread.  To do this properly, use [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)), which will not wait for the work to complete, or [`SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)), which will.